# When and where?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory

And remember, mankind is not the science-community alone. What did it bring my neighbor, my baker, the postman, the policeman around the corner, etc.?

Comment: Technology as you know it?!

Comment: Vague. My neighbor does not understand your answer.

Comment: ....Everything?

Comment: Another vague answer.

Comment: The phone/ laptop you have used to ask this question has billions of transistors inside it. They were made due to the amazing advances in quantum theory back in the first half of the 20th century.

Comment: Does your neighbor use a laser printer? Nuclear-generated electricity? chemical compounds (plastics, nanomaterials, alloys) anywhere in his life. Does he  watch  episodes  of "The 1900 island" to notice differences? Does he rely on the plane's GPS when he flies?

Answer (score 5):

Some low hanging fruit:

- All computing devices and most electronics use transistors and amplifiers that rely on (and were invented only with knowledge of) certain quantum mechanical principles.
- GPS relies on atomic clocks which in turn rely on knowledge of quantum mechanics.
- [Lasers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_laser_applications) rely on quantum mechanics and are used for communication, medicine, industry, military, law enforcement, research, commercial products, and entertainment. List taken from [lasers wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser#Uses).

There are many many more but these come to mind quickly.